# Error when using ggcuminc from the package ggsurvfit

Tags: ggplot2

I have been getting an error when plotting a cumulative incidence function using `ggcuminc` from the package `ggsurvfit`.

Here is an example:

```
cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) %>%
    ggcuminc(outcome = "death from cancer") +
    geom_step(linewidth = 1)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `geom_step()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_step()` requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
```

This error is recent and occurred in the last 2 months. I can't figure out what happened exactly. Any ideas?

btw: The `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0, and was replaced with `linewidth` instead.

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

Looking at the source code you can pass linewidth/linetype/etc parameters to `ggcuminc()` directly via the [ellipsis (dot-dot-dot) argument](https://github.com/ddsjoberg/ggsurvfit/blob/e5cb0e2f495a9ac73147779f9b37d110cf046623/R/ggcuminc.R), e.g.

```r
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
# install.packages("tidycmprsk")
library(tidycmprsk)

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) %>%
  ggcuminc(linewidth = 0.5, lty = 2)
#> Plotting outcome "death from cancer".
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Hopefully this will work for your use-case, but if not please leave a comment and I'll see what other potential workarounds there might be.

---

### Original answer:

I don't understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to plot `geom_step()` on top of your `ggcuminc()` step you can specify your x and y axes and add `inherit.aes = FALSE`, e.g.

```r
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
# install.packages("tidycmprsk")
library(tidycmprsk)

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ 1, trial) %>%
  ggcuminc()
#> Plotting outcome "death from cancer".
```

[image]

```r
cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ 1, trial) %>%
  ggcuminc() +
  geom_step(aes(x = time, y = estimate),
            linewidth = 2,
            inherit.aes = FALSE)
#> Plotting outcome "death from cancer".
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
I am trying to edit the size of the lines in the plot generated by ggcuminc. This used to work previously just by adding `+ geom_step(size = 1)`. For some reason it does not function any more.

I don't want to overlay the original plot generated with `ggcuminc` with an extra layer. I want to change the original plot by editing it's aesthetics.

Your suggestion doesn't solve the problem. If you rerun your example with `Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial)` for different treatment groups, the plot won't be correct.

Comment: Ohh - sorry, I get it now - I'll update my answer